# Vue syntax rendered after page load

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core

I am a newbie in Vue.js. I am currently using Vue.js on top of asp.net core.

I noticed that in 99% time page is served before Vue.js syntax is rendered. How can I prevent this from happening?

**For example**

When page load first I see

```
<ol>
<li v-for="u in subscribers">{{ u.name }} - {{u.email}}</li>
</ol>
```

And then after split of a second I see

```
<ol>
<li>John - john@domain.com</li>
<li>John1 - joh1n@domain.com</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Vue is by default added in the browser so if you want it to be rendered while the page loads you need to do it on the server

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I have updated my question

Comment: You’ll need to show an [mcve] where this happens so we know how you’ve done this. Usually components contain templates separately and they aren’t in the page source and therefore won’t be shown to anyone. There’s only the placeholder into which the component is attached.

Comment: I am not using components. I simply created this project https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1271379/Simple-ASP-NET-CORE-2-2-App-plusVue-JS

Comment: That explains it. It will always show the Vue syntax first because that’s what the browser gets and only later Vue will run. If you don’t want that then you can make it into a component and it’ll work better

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen is this a good starting point to learn about vue components? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Yes, that’s a good place to go forward. In the code you’ve used there already is a Vue component in JavaScript, only the template part is inside the HTML. So you’re almost using Vue components as they should be used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188685/discussion-between-mko-and-sami-kuhmonen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the template is written inside the page HTML code it will always be shown first by the browser when it’s loading the page. Usually Vue components include a template which is used to render the data and this won’t happen.

You can take the template that is written on the page and add it to the Vue [component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) so it will use it to render, not the contents of the page. The simplest way is to just add the template as a parameter to the Vue component, but later on it may be better to use separate template files, or [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) which may take a bit more work.